# Custom Serialization in Hazelcast

Tags: serialization, hazelcast

Can someone explain the significance of Hazelcast Custom Serialization techniques :-

1. StreamSerializer
2. ByteArraySerializer

I have gone through Hazelcast official documentation but it's not very clear from that.

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice blog writeup at https://hazelcast.com/blog/comparing-serialization-methods